# Check if a small image (with difference in color) is inside a big image?

Tags: c#, image-processing

I know how to check if a small image is inside a bigger one but my problem is :

I need to check if a small image (with difference in color) is inside a big image?

As you can see in the picture, the small image is exactly part of big image.

I know i can convert both to black-white image to check but what if there is difference in color depth also?

Any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: If color doesn't have large difference, you can make problem really simple. Make them gray-scale and do binning of 5-6 levels. If color diff can be very large, consider edge/contour based analysis.

Answer (score 1):

AForge has the ability to do this using the ExhaustiveTemplateMatching class.

Previously discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443862/find-a-smaller-image-within-another-big-one-and-fast).

Comment: This is exactly what i'm looking for!!! Tyvm!1!

Answer (score 0):

You could try an [Edge Detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_detection) algorithm. If the sub-image has not been skewed or scaled, it should just be a simple matter of finding the edges of both images and comparing different sections of the bigger picture with the small one.

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93642/Canny-Edge-Detection-in-C) looks like a good reference implementation of a simple edge detection algorithm.